# Zapier form dynamic inputFields manipulation

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I'd like to manipulate the input fields of a trigger form dynamically:

- I have a trigger 'hidden' with a combo-box in a form
- Each time I update the combo, it should add one or more combo-boxes in the same form depending on the value

I couldn't find any way to access the `operation.inputFields` somewhere for doing an update on this list dynamically, whether via the `bundle` or else...

Here is the small example: https://github.com/nuxeo-sandbox/nuxeo-zapier/blob/spikes-NXP-26085-zapier/nuxeo-zapier-app/triggers/project.js#L8-L16

Thank you for your help!
Vlad

Comment: Are you using Zapier CLI for your APP?

Comment: Yes. I updated the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

It sounds like you're looking for `Custom Fields`: https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli#customdynamic-fields

In addition to a static list of input fields, you can provide a function that will run and provide a dynamic set of fields. It's how we get inputs for each column in a google sheet:

[image]

Is that what you're asking? Modifying the `inputFields` array at runtime probably doesn't do what you want.

Comment: David, I'm sorry for the spam, indeed I have missed the "recipes" example in your link. I can totally create on the fly some fields. Thank you very much!

Comment: @xavdid - Are dynamic fields supported for Triggers? I'm using Zapier via its web UI, and while I can see the option to add a dynamic field when creating an Action, the same choice is unavailable when creating a Trigger (the button is labeled "Add User Input Field" rather than "Add v" and it isn't a dropdown).

Comment: dynamic fields in triggers are fine per the schema, but there may be a restriction in the Visual Builder; i don't remember offhand

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, there seems to be a restriction at the builder level. It's helpful to know that it shouldn't be there if I switch to CLI.